# Regarding click event bind in anchor tag Signal R

Tags: jquery, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

Hello I am binding My chat friend list using ajax call like this

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/getdata.asmx/GetUserInfo",
            data: "{'Id':'" + gorge + "'   }",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(errorThrown); },
            success: function (xml) {
                //alert('success');
                $('#frndcontact li').remove();
                // $("#frndcontact").innerhtml("");
                // DivMainContainer                
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(xml.d);
                // alert(data);
                if (obj.length > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                        // var name = obj[i].name;
                        var objname = "'" + obj[i].name + "'";
                        //alert(name);
                        var H = '<li style="font-size:11px;font-family:\'lucida grande\',tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;">' +
                            '<img alt="" height="18px" width="18px" id="test-' + obj[i].friendid + '" src="Images/offline.png" />' +
                            '<a class="UserItem" id="test-' + obj[i].friendid + '" >' + obj[i].name + '</a>' +
                            '</li>'
                        $("#frndcontact").append(H);

                    }

                }

            }
        });
```

Then after below is my Signal R Code

```
  $.connection.hub.qs = "Id=" + gorge;

        var chat = $.connection.chat3Hub;
        chat.client.foo = function () { };

        $.connection.hub.start(function () {
            // chat.server.OnConnected();
            //  chat.server.getAllOnlineStatus();
        });

        chat.client.disconnect = function (connectionId, userList) {
            $(userList).each(function (index, obj) {
                $("#test-" + obj).attr('src', 'images/offline.png');
                $("#test-" + obj).next('.UserItem').removeClass('online');
            });
        };
        chat.client.disconnectuservialogout = function (connectionId, userList) {
            $(userList).each(function (index, obj) {
                $("#test-" + obj).attr('src', 'images/offline.png');
                $("#test-" + obj).next('.UserItem').removeClass('online');

            });
        };
        chat.client.joined = function (connectionId, userList) {
            $(userList).each(function (index, obj) {
                $("#test-" + obj).attr('src', 'images/online.png');
                $("#test-" + obj).next('.UserItem').addClass('online');


            });
        };
        $('.logout').click(function () {
            chat.server.disconectonlogout();
        });
        **//THIS CODE IS NOT WORKING DONT KNOW WHY**
        **$('.UserItem').click(function () {
            var chatWindow = $("#divChatWindow").clone(true);
            $("#chatContainer").append(chatWindow);
        });**

        // $.connection.hub.server.connected = function () { }
    });
```

But when i execute below code I am binding event to anchor tag which has class Useritem..but when i put breakpoint in javascript of firefox debugger it is not coming.so what to do since i am not able to bind click event of anchor tag..Please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because the `$('.UserItem').click()` declaration only works on items that exist when it's being executed. Read up on http://api.jquery.com/on/ to see how to add event handlers to all elements in the future as well.

```
$(document).on("click", ".UserItem", function () {
    var chatWindow = $("#divChatWindow").clone(true);
    $("#chatContainer").append(chatWindow);
});
```

The above should get you going in the right direction.